How does a war end?
To start an optional war, the full Sanhedrin must approve (Sanhedrin 2a.). A mandatory war would be defensive, against the 7 nations, or against Amalek.
How do these wars end?
For example, did the war with the Romans end when Masada was captured, the Persians drove out the Romans in 614, or the Eastern Roman Empire fell in 1453?
What kind of halachic act, if any, is needed to end the sate of war?

A mandatory war ends when the grounds for war no longer exist (amalek perishes -iy"h soon! , the nation is no longer under threat, etc.) As for an optional war, I wonder if perhaps the question for the Urim V'tumim needed an end goal to be specified before there would be any response...

So when did the Roman war end? It would have been mandatory and the need to get rid of them to restore the temple persisted after 70

"To start an optional war, the Urim v Thumim must be consulted." Source?

Apologies. I must have been taught wrong. I can only find a source for the sanhedrin being involved.

No need for apologies! Thanks for editing :) Also, take a gander at ch. 6 of H. Melakhim (in particular halakhah 4)... does it answer your question to satisfaction?

It only describes total victory conditions. I am more asking about defeat or settled ends of the war. Is your answer that we must fight until the enemy is anihilated or forced to pay tribute AND accept the 7 mitzvot to our satisfaction? I would think that with the Roman War, the Sanhedrin accepts defeat as part of their move to Yavneh but do we need to keep fighting them until the Romans submit to our might?
